# Call to undefined function register_custom_styles()

Tags: php, wordpress

I have been trying to add a custom css file based on a condition. That's why I wanted to register that css file. But getting fatal error saying

**Fatal error: Call to undefined function register_custom_styles() in /home/learnenglish/public_html/wp-content/themes/learn/functions.php on line 899**

Here is the code in the below:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    if (!register_custom_styles()) {
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_custom_styles' );
        function register_plugin_styles() {
            wp_register_style( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri( '/custom.css' ) );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'custom' );
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: @developerme He mentioned in his question that where he write this function check this line.
/home/learnenglish/public_html/wp-content/themes/learn/functions.php on line 899

Answer (score 0):

Just try This

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_custom_styles' );
}

function register_custom_styles() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri('/custom.css' ) );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom' );
}
```

Comment: You are calling `register_custom_styles`, but you created function `register_plugin_styles`. Your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, the function you are calling is not defined, and which one you've defined is with another function name

```
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if (!register_custom_styles()) {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_custom_styles' );
            function register_custom_styles() { // change here to register_custom_styles
                wp_register_style( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri( '/custom.css' ) );
                wp_enqueue_style( 'custom' );
            }
        }
}
```

change the function name and it will work

Answer (score 0):

Please try This function. the function register_custom_styles you are calling is not defined, and which one you've defined is with another function name.

```
 if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        if (!register_plugin_styles()) {
            add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'register_plugin_styles' );
            function register_plugin_styles() {
                wp_register_style( 'custom', get_stylesheet_directory_uri( '/custom.css' ) );
                wp_enqueue_style( 'custom' );
            }
        }


}
```

Comment: You are calling `register_custom_styles`, but you created function `register_plugin_styles`. Your answer is wrong.

Comment: Sorry That is my mistake!!